# Mail - send web content as link by default

Tags: safari, mail.app

If I choose to share a page with Safari, it automatically re-loads the entire web page in a Mail "new message" window. I can then choose to send web content as "Link Only", which removes all of the content that was just downloaded.

I routinely block a lot of trackers, ads, etc in my browser, and I don't want to lose all that protection when sharing a page. Also, first downloading a lot of content and then deleting it is bad practice.

Is there a way to set Mail to send it as link only by default?

Comment: **1** how are you going from safari to mail ? I mean by a toolbar icon or File > share > mail. **2** I haven't found any settings,  but this https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mail/mail40723/12.0/mac/10.14.6 says : "*When you share a webpage from the Safari app.. you can choose the format in which to email it.*" I think I had chosen link at that time and now I always see link. there could be something in the plist files. **3** Try that in a new user account.

Comment: By File > Share > Email this Page. you're right, it remembers your choice.(I  shouldn't use so many different computers. Thanks!)

Comment: So we're looking for a way to reset it now ?